How do I use Euler in Modern Toolchains with digits of different style?
Regarding the question “How do I use AMS Euler?”, I need to modify the reply of Davislor to suit my requirements, as described below.
Odd (1, 3, 5, 7, 9): the font is Cambria.
Even (2, 4, 6, 8): the font is Calibri.
Zero (0): the font is Courier Std and the font size is twice as the others.
Based on “Euler plus Palatino” combinations, please advise which line of the below code should change and how.
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathup{d}}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%%%
% Set up your text and math fonts
%%%

\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}, frak, bffrak, cal},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/num, bfup/num, it, bfit, scr, bfscr,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt}
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfcal, Scale=MatchUppercase, Alternate]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
  Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
  singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
  rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
  points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
  \[
    \frac{1}{2\symup{\pi i}} \int\limits_\gamma f\Bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\Bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
  Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
  continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
  \[
    \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
  \]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\Biggl(\max\Biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \Biggr\}\Biggr)\,.
\]
\end{document}


what do you mean by your note at the end? and why do you say you're using fonts when your code uses a completely different set? note that if you ask a question which requires commercial fonts, only people who have those fonts can test your code. that rules out a significant group of potential helpers.

@cfr I mean I should use commercial fonts for digits which may not be at disposal of all users. So, I asked my question with fonts like Cambria, Calibri, and Courier Std. No mater which font will be used, I just want to find out the concept of solution. The note is an answer to a potential question which says, CLibri, Cambria, or Courier Std fonts are not visually matching the other fonts.

@cfr I deleted that unnecessary note to avoid confusion.

You like patchwork, don't you?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}



\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathup{d}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


%%%
% Set up your text and math fonts
%%%

\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={"0000-"0001,"0020-"007E,
                    "00A0,"00A7-"00A8,"00AC,"00AF,"00B1,"00B4-"00B5,"00B7,
                    "00D7,"00F7,
                    "0131,
                    "0237,"02C6-"02C7,"02D8-"02DA,"02DC,
                    "0300-"030C,"030F,"0311,"0323-"0325,"032E-"0332,"0338,
                    "0391-"0393,"0395-"03A1,"03A3-"03A8,"03B1-"03BB,
                    "03BD-"03C1,"03C3-"03C9,"03D1,"03D5-"03D6,"03F5,
                    "2016,"2018-"2019,"2021,"2026-"202C,"2032-"2037,"2044,
                    "2057,"20D6-"20D7,"20DB-"20DD,"20E1,"20EE-"20EF,
                    "210B-"210C,"210E-"2113,"2118,"211B-"211C,"2126-"2128,
                    "212C-"212D,"2130-"2131,"2133,"2135,"2190-"2199,
                    "21A4,"21A6,"21A9-"21AA,"21BC-"21CC,"21D0-"21D5,
                    "2200,"2202-"2209,"220B-"220C,"220F-"2213,"2215-"221E,
                    "2223,"2225,"2227-"222E,"2234-"2235,"2237-"223D,
                    "2240-"224C,"2260-"2269,"226E-"2279,"2282-"228B,"228E,
                    "2291-"2292,"2295-"2299,"22A2-"22A5,"22C0-"22C5,
                    "22DC-"22DD,"22EF,"22F0-"22F1,
                    "2308-"230B,"2320-"2321,"2329-"232A,"239B-"23AE,
                    "23DC-"23DF,
                    "27E8-"27E9,"27F5-"27FE,"2A0C,"2B1A,
                    "1D400-"1D433,"1D49C,"1D49E-"1D49F,"1D4A2,"1D4A5-"1D4A6,
                    "1D4A9-"1D4AC,"1D4AE-"1D4B5,"1D4D0-"1D4E9,"1D504-"1D505,
                    "1D507-"1D50A,"1D50D-"1D514,"1D516-"1D51C,"1D51E-"1D537,
                    "1D56C-"1D59F,"1D6A8-"1D6B8,"1D6BA-"1D6D2,"1D6D4-"1D6DD,
                    "1D6DF,"1D6E1,"1D7CE-"1D7D7
                   }]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={bfup/{latin, Latin, greek, Greek}, frak, bffrak, cal},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={up/num, bfup/num, it, bfit, scr, bfscr,
                    sfup, sfit, bfsfup, bfsfit, tt}
            ]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bfcal, Scale=MatchUppercase, Alternate]{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=bb, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Latin Modern Math}

\newfontface{\cambria}{Cambria}[NFSSFamily=cambria]
\newfontface{\calibri}{Calibri}[NFSSFamily=calibri]
\newfontface{\courier}{Courier}[NFSSFamily=courier]
\DeclareSymbolFont{cambria}{TU}{cambria}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{calibri}{TU}{calibri}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{courier}{TU}{courier}{m}{n}

\Umathcode`0="7 \symcourier `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symcambria `1
\Umathcode`3="7 \symcambria `3
\Umathcode`5="7 \symcambria `5
\Umathcode`7="7 \symcambria `7
\Umathcode`9="7 \symcambria `9
\Umathcode`2="6 \symcalibri `2
\Umathcode`4="6 \symcalibri `4
\Umathcode`6="6 \symcalibri `6
\Umathcode`8="6 \symcalibri `8

\begin{document}

$0123456789$

\begin{theorem}[Residue theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma f\bigl(x^{\mathbf{N}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times 10}}\bigr)
    = \sum_{k=1}^m n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Maximum modulus]
Let $G$ be a bounded open set in $\BbbC$ and suppose that $f$ is a
continuous function on $G^-$ which is analytic in $G$. Then
\[
  \max\{\, |f(z)|\mathrel{:}z\in G^- \,\} = \max\{\, |f(z)|:z\in \partial G \,\}\,.
\]
\end{theorem}

First some large operators both in text:
$\iiint\limits_{Q}f(x,y,z) \diff x \diff y \diff z$
and
$\prod_{\gamma\in\Gamma_{\bar{C}}}\partial(\tilde{X}_\gamma)$;\
and also on display
\[
  \iiiint\limits_{Q}f(w,x,y,z) \diff w \diff x \diff y \diff z
  \leq
  \oint_{\partial Q} f'\biggl(\max\biggl\{
  \frac{\Vert w\Vert}{\vert w^2+x^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert z\Vert}{\vert y^2+z^2\vert};
  \frac{\Vert w\oplus z\Vert}{\vert x\oplus y\vert}
  \biggr\}\biggr)\,.
\]

\end{document}


With colors to better show the different fonts used for the digits.


Thanks for your consideration. I ran this MWE in two OS and two engines; Windows 10 and Debian, Xetex and Luatex. In all situations, I faced compiler errors. By the way, I have to, due to some reasons, use only Xetex and Windows 10. Also, I need the zero to be twice as others in size.

I don't like patchwork actually (-:    Somehow, I have to distinguish some digits which is more complicated than my question. I simplified it and I just want to find out the pattern; then modify it to suit my case.

@Abbas I get no error.
